# GWT Hangs at startup of the application before onModuleLoad

Tags: java, gwt, gxt

We have GWT/GXT 3 application (mostly migrated from gxt 2 but still has a few little areas that are not updated yet). The application will hang at its loading screen (just a div with a spinning gif) and not complete, this however only happens on IE8 for just one of our clients.

It does not reach onModuleLoad to start the app and appear to hang during downloading of the javascript. **Is there any more I can do to debug this?**

**Little More Information**

User Agent -
`Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; chromeframe/23.0.1271.95; .NET CLR 1.0.3705; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; InfoPath.1; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; InfoPath.2)`

Software in use - `GWT, GXT, Spring, Comet, JMS`

Client likely has both a proxy and firewall neither of which we can control.

**Edit**
Added to mention this is a live system which works for all other clients and is only an intermittent problem for the client in question

Comment: DO you have any error in the Developement mode tab ?

Comment: @Moh sorry I should have specified this is a live system already in use by a number of our other clients, it is just this client that it is not working for. However when run in development mode there is no errors at at startup (there is a warning about some non-standard css rules but thats about it)

Comment: Is there a chrome Frame installed? The useragent looks like

Comment: If you have access to the JS console of the browser you should have clearer error.

Comment: @ChristianKuetbach Good spot, gxt has a UserPropertyAgentGenerator which uses ua.contains("chrome"), however chromeframe still shows up in user agent string even if it disabled so that could be the reason... I will set up a test for this case :)

Answer (score 2):

You can set the uncaughtExceptionHandler and display the errors on screen.

Take a look at this example:
https://github.com/dankurka/mgwt.showcase/blob/master/src/main/java/com/googlecode/mgwt/examples/showcase/client/ShowCaseEntryPoint.java

```
@Override
public void onModuleLoad() {
    GWT.setUncaughtExceptionHandler(new UncaughtExceptionHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onUncaughtException(Throwable e) {
            Window.alert("uncaught: " + e.getMessage());
            String s = buildStackTrace(e, "RuntimeExceotion:\n");
            Window.alert(s);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
    new Timer() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            start();
        }
    }.schedule(1);
}
```

If you set the UncaughtExceptionHandler within the `onModuleLoad` and don't use a `Timer`, nothing what happens in this method will be logged.

Comment: thankyou for your answer, The problem is that the onModuleLoad is never reached we have a log entry at the very start and it doesn't get logged in this scenario.

Comment: If this logger will cause an aexception , you would be unable to see it. In general it is a good idea to set the UncaughtExceptionHandler